# Visualize PCD containing custom double point structure

Tags: double, visualization, precision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have created a custom double point-type for storing the point position in the PCD file. I required the double data type since my points are in global coordinates and have very large values (of order 10^6 to 10^7) and require good precision. Since the values are large and the default FLOAT32 precision is limited, there is considerable data approximation which is also visible during visualization.

I created this PCD by transforming the raw pointcloud with the initial global reference coordinate from GPS in the data bag that I have. I am using a 15 point precision.

I created a separate script for visualizing this custom point-type PCD. But by visually comparing, I cannot see any considerable difference between the FLOAT32 and double data-type PCD's.

[Raw_float_pcd_visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPZzI.png)

[Transformed_float_pcd_visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORE1A.png)

[Transformed_double_pcd_visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjdb8.png)

You can see that the transformed_double and transformed_float PCD's are quite similar and approximated. While the raw_float PCD is quite good as compared to these two.

I am attaching the PCD files for reference:

[raw_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15N6vSumcmVmDNhtsZA_HEmGEP1vPVubk/view?usp=sharing)

[transformed_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAbbrLMSIeCjRAGRPHtxFD3Vl-xKMPnW/view?usp=sharing)

[transformed_double](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xTxg1b9D8A_aAZOAfVen7HGioDXVyKK/view?usp=sharing)

I think that I am skipping some things while loading the pointcloud and there are some more changes that need to be done in order to visualize the points with double point precision.

I used "pcl_viewer" from pcl_tools for visualizing FLOAT type PCD's.

Code for visualizaing custom DOUBLE point-structure PCD:

```
#define PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE
#include <iostream>

// #include "double_viz/pcl_double.h"
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/common/common.h>
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl-1.7/pcl/point_types.h>

namespace pcl
{
  #define PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D_DOUBLE \
    union EIGEN_ALIGN16 { \
      double data[4]; \
      struct { \
        double x; \
        double y; \
        double z; \
      }; \
    };

  struct _PointXYZDouble
  {
    PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D_DOUBLE; // This adds the members x,y,z which can also be accessed using the point (which is float[4])

    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  };

  struct EIGEN_ALIGN16 PointXYZDouble : public _PointXYZDouble
  {
    inline PointXYZDouble (const _PointXYZDouble &p)
    {
      x = p.x; y = p.y; z = p.z; data[3] = 1.0;
    }

    inline PointXYZDouble ()
    {
      x = y = z = 0.0;
      data[3] = 1.0;
    }

    inline PointXYZDouble (double _x, double _y, double _z)
    {
      x = _x; y = _y; z = _z;
      data[3] = 1.0;
    }

    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  };
}

  POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_STRUCT (pcl::_PointXYZDouble,
    (double, x, x)
    (double, y, y)
    (double, z, z)
  )
  POINT_CLOUD_REGISTER_POINT_WRAPPER(pcl::PointXYZDouble, pcl::_PointXYZDouble)


// This function displays the help
void
showHelp(char * program_name)
{
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Usage: " << program_name << " cloud_filename.[pcd]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "-h:  Show this help." << std::endl;
}

// This is the main function
int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{

  // Show help
  if (pcl::console::find_switch (argc, argv, "-h") || pcl::console::find_switch (argc, argv, "--help")) 
  {
    showHelp (argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }

  // Fetch point cloud filename in arguments | Works with PCD
  std::vector<int> filenames;

  if (filenames.size () != 1)  
  {
    filenames = pcl::console::parse_file_extension_argument (argc, argv, ".pcd");

    if (filenames.size () != 1) 
    {
      showHelp (argv[0]);
      return -1;
    } 
  }

  // Load file | Works with PCD and PLY files
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZDouble>::Ptr source_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZDouble> ());

    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile (argv[filenames[0]], *source_cloud) < 0)  
    {
      std::cout << "Error loading point cloud " << argv[filenames[0]] << std::endl << std::endl;
      showHelp (argv[0]);
      return -1;
    }
  // Visualization
//   printf(  "\nPoint cloud colors :  white  = original point cloud\n"
//       "                        red  = transformed point cloud\n");
  pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer ("Visualize double PCL");

   // Define R,G,B colors for the point cloud
  pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerCustom<pcl::PointXYZDouble> source_cloud_color_handler (source_cloud, 100, 100, 100);
  // We add the point cloud to the viewer and pass the color handler
  viewer.addPointCloud (source_cloud, source_cloud_color_handler, "original_cloud");

  viewer.addCoordinateSystem (1.0, "cloud", 0);
  viewer.setBackgroundColor(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0); // Setting background to a dark grey
  viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_OPACITY, 1, "original_cloud");
  viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "original_cloud");
  viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties (pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_LINE_WIDTH, 1, "original_cloud");
  //viewer.setPosition(800, 400); // Setting visualiser window position

  while (!viewer.wasStopped ()) // Display the visualiser until 'q' key is pressed
  { 
    viewer.spinOnce ();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [raw_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15N6vSumcmVmDNhtsZA_HEmGEP1vPVubk/view?usp=sharing) file, the size field has been defined as 4 bytes each: `SIZE 4 4 4 4`,
to be read as double it should be `SIZE 8 8 8 8`.

With your current implementation each field is being read as Float32

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.
I used the [raw_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15N6vSumcmVmDNhtsZA_HEmGEP1vPVubk/view?usp=sharing) PCD to generate [transformed_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAbbrLMSIeCjRAGRPHtxFD3Vl-xKMPnW/view?usp=sharing) and [transformed_double](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xTxg1b9D8A_aAZOAfVen7HGioDXVyKK/view?usp=sharing) PCD's. I was losing point pecision after transforming, hence I generated {SIZE 8 8 8} type PCD and it is being read as Float64. While the other two are being read as Float32.

Comment: I checked out your code, the PCD file is being read and visualized properly.    
After observing the `transformed_float` and `transformed_double` files, there was not much difference in the values there was only a precision loss in the order of a few centimeters.     
Such a small difference would not be clearly visible on visualization, hence converting to double will not yield any visual difference.     
Your code and PCD files are being correctly visualized.

Comment: Yes, the difference is small. 
In the [raw_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15N6vSumcmVmDNhtsZA_HEmGEP1vPVubk/view?usp=sharing) pointcloud the points are sparse. While in [transformed_float](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TAbbrLMSIeCjRAGRPHtxFD3Vl-xKMPnW/view?usp=sharing) the points distributed in the form of lines. These remarks I make on the basis of what I visually saw. To me, data approximation looks as the most plausible reason for this.

Now, consider a use case where I need to do scan matching for localization. Will this approximation cause any difference?

Comment: Why is there any difference in visualization in case of [transformed_double](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xTxg1b9D8A_aAZOAfVen7HGioDXVyKK/view?usp=sharing) PCD? I checked inside the PCD file reader and verified that the points are being parsed as Float64.